# how to save data using ajax in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I don't want to submit a form but i want to get the value of a input field and send it to controller via ajax to be save in database.
I have this below JS code to help me get the content of the input field and send to the server side after 3 second of user input

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(document).ready(function(){
    //setup before functions
    var typingTimer;
    var doneTypingInterval = 3000;
    var \$TitleInput = $('#product-product_title');

    //on keyup, start the countdown

    \$TitleInput.on('keyup input change paste',function(){
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if (\$TitleInput.val()) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    });
    //user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping () {

        data = \$TitleInput.val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/trobay/draft/create',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) { 
                // handle error
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

in my controller i have this

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Draft();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->created_at = \time();
        if($model->save()){
            echo draftId;
        }else{
            echo '0';
        }

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I want to echo back the draftid if the title was draft was save successfully
how to make this work plase any help on this

below is my view

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => $model->formName(),
    'enableClientValidation' => true,
    'fieldConfig' => ['template' => '{label}{input}{hint}']
]); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'product_title')->textInput([
                'class' => 'title-input',
                'placeholder' => 'Give us a title for your items(include size,brand,color,material. e.t.c)',
            ])->label(false) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 text-muted">E.g Men's blue addidas glide running shoes size 11 </div>
    </div>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'user_id')->textInput() ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'product_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'product_description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->textInput() ?>
```

i have this in my view but i would like to only save the value of the first input field after 3 second that user entered there value

Comment: Please, show your view with form

Comment: @Vitaly thanks i have updated my question and i have added my view

Comment: i want to add the value to DB each time a user value changes so am not waiting for users to fill up all the form and submit

Answer (score 0):

Try this JS, but change `$('#form')` on your ID form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //setup before functions
    var typingTimer;
    var doneTypingInterval = 3000;
    var $form = $('#form');

    //on keyup, start the countdown

    $form.find('input[type="text"]').on('keyup input change paste',function(){
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if ($(this).val()) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    });
    //user is "finished typing," do something
    function doneTyping () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/trobay/draft/create',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, errMsg) { 
                // handle error
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
});
```